# SIP - connection

Tags: sip

I am making a web-system for a callcenter, where I need an integration to SIP (so I can call phonenumbers). 
I found this tool that looks like it's suitable as a softphone. https://www.doubango.org/sipml5/call.htm?svn=170

I have made an test account at sipdiscount.com (it looked cheap) that I suppose, I can connect to doubango's softphone tool. But how do I connect? What is private/public identity? And do you have any better suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a SIP Proxy (UAS) you only need Host Name or IP Address AND username/password.  Also, online SIP providers typically give your a Trunk, which can be used telephone number to dial-out and/or accept new calls.  However, SIP provides provide trunks and allow you to define your own telephone numbers, which route through the SIP trunk. Default UDP port is 5060.  For security purposes, some SIP providers provide SSL\TLS over TCP port 5061, while others support DTLS over UDP port 5061.

private/public identity is not part of SIP protocol, so might be some proprietary doubango thing.  I never used doubango, so not sure.  I've been using Zoiper, which is the most basic SIP Phone and a UI that is common to all softphones.